# Angularjs security with OAuth

Tags: angularjs, security, oauth

I have an angular fornt-end app witch connected to a back-end app via API

The angular app required login before the user can access it, the login is based on OAuth so the angular app have info for API-end point and client secret.

The issue is even when I am not singed in I can see main.js via browser and can see API-end point and client secret.

I am not able to find a good solution after a lot of reading.

My question is: what is the best practices to hide such info OR, how can I load all angular files after the user have already singed in.

Any Ideas?

Thanks

Comment: which flow are you using?

Comment: Currently:

User tring to access angularjs app then check if access token is exist. 
If yes, load app if not, redirect to login page.